# Why "Getting Started with the Facebook SDK for Android" example doesn't work?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to create my first Facebook Android Application but it doesn't work.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

It doesn't print my name in "hello word" string and The app enters in a infinite loop.

Main Class

```
package com.firstandroidappalf;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

// start Facebook Login
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

  // callback when session changes state
  @Override
  public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (session.isOpened()) {

      // make request to the /me API
      Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
          if (user != null) {
            TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
            welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
}

@Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.firstandroidappalf"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.firstandroidappalf.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

String resourc

```
<string name="app_name">First Android App</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
 <string name="app_id">6427XXXX9097984</string>
```

keyhashes

http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download/keyhash.zip

Log cat Errors:

12-19 17:16:19.870: E/SpannableStringBuilder(19027): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-19 17:16:19.870: E/SpannableStringBuilder(19027): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-19 17:36:19.785: E/SpannableStringBuilder(19027): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
12-19 17:36:19.785: E/SpannableStringBuilder(19027): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

[image: facebook dev]

Comment: Define "doesn't work." How does it not work. What fails and what are you seeing? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see exactly what is failing and if the values of variables are what you expect?

Comment: I would put breakpoints on if (session.isOpened()) and on if (user != null) to start.

Comment: I did.. session.isOpened() is always false...

Comment: I solved, I posted my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 day I solved. 
The problem was the keyhash to put on android developer because the keyhash created with openssl or the tool in http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/download/keyhash.zip is wrong.

My correct solution is below but for more information about this issue you can look

Troubleshooting section in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/

```
//imports:

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.*;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try {
       **//be careful to put the correct package name, it was mmy first mistake**
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("[your package name, e.g.    com.yourcompany.yourapp]", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.d("Hash Key:","Hash Key " +Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));

        }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
   ...
  }
```

**Finding "Hash Key:" in Logcat's messages you find up the correct keyhash.**